# Custom error messages in package for Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, package

I am creating a package for Laravel 5.4 and have a few custom regexes with error messages. Normally you put these messages in de validation.php file (which works). But when installing a package I want the user to not have to copy paste those in.

Is there way for a package to have an extra validation language file that will automatically be called when the rule is not found in the regular validation language file?

Comment: Haven't used it but https://github.com/joshbrw/laravel-validation-rule-registration may be useful or at least lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I've run into the exact same issue. The validation rule registration plugin helps to register the rule into the global space, but doesn't look like it resolves this issue. Especially given custom packages with validation will require very specific attribute messages.

Answer (score 0):

OK Figured it out.

If you're using Validator::make() call. You can do this

```
$fields = [
    "fieldA" => "Testing",
    "fieldB" => "TextB",
];

$rules = [
    "fieldA" => [
        "alpha",
    ],
    "fieldB" => [
        "regex:/TextC/",
    ],
];

$messages = [
    "fieldA.alpha" => "Sorry champ, but fieldA must be only characters",
    "fieldB.regex" => "The regex failed here",
];

$validator = Validator::make($fields, $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) return $validator->messages()->all();
```

I haven't tested this code - mine is a little different, but this should work.

Reference here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-error-messages